# LINQ generating Nested/Sub queries

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using  Asp.NET & Entity Framework with SQL Server as Database, somehow I am getting this strange issue

I have this code:

```
var pricingInfo = (from price in invDB.Pricing.AsNoTracking()
                                   join priceD in invDB.PricingDetail.AsNoTracking() on price.PricingId equals priceDtl.PricingId
                                   join tagD in invDB.PricingTagDetail.AsNoTracking() on priceDtl.PricingDetailId equals tagDtl.PricingDetailId
                                   join it in invDB.Item.AsNoTracking() on tagDtl.ItemId equals item.ItemId
                                   join par in invDB.Party.AsNoTracking() on tagDtl.PartyId equals party.PartyId
                                   join b in invDB.Brand.AsNoTracking() on tagDtl.BrandId equals brd.BrandId into t from brand in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   where tagDtl.AvailableQuantity > 0m && price.PricingNo == printNumber
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       TagNo = tagDtl.TagNo,
                                       SellingRate = tagDtl.SellingRate,
                                       Quantity = tagDtl.AvailableQuantity ?? 0m,
                                       ItemCode = item.Name,
                                       UOMId = priceDtl.UOMId,
                                       Brand = brand.BrandCode,
                                       Supplier = party.PartyCode,
                                       Offer = tagDtl.Offer
                                   }).ToList();
```

Which generates the below sql query with a sub query, without where condition and it pulls out full records from a large volume data. This results to a heavy memory consumption and performance issues.

```
SELECT
    [Filter1].[PricingId1] AS [PricingId],
    [Filter1].[TagNo] AS [TagNo],
    [Filter1].[SellingRate1] AS [SellingRate],
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[AvailableQuantity] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as decimal(18)) ELSE [Filter1].[AvailableQuantity] END AS [C1],
    [Filter1].[Name] AS [Name],
    [Filter1].[UOMId 1] AS [UOMId ],
    [Extent6].[BrandCode] AS [BrandCode],
    [Filter1].[PartyCode] AS [PartyCode],
    [Filter1].[Offer] AS [Offer]
    FROM  

(

SELECT [Extent1].[PricingId] AS [PricingId1], [Extent1].[PricingNo] AS [PricingNo], [Extent2].[UnitOfMeasurementId] AS [UnitOfMeasurementId1], [Extent3].[TagNo] AS [TagNo], [Extent3].[BrandId] AS [BrandId1], [Extent3].[SellingRate] AS [SellingRate1], [Extent3].[AvailableQuantity] AS [AvailableQuantity], [Extent3].[Offer] AS [Offer], [Extent4].[Name] AS [Name], [Extent5].[PartyCode] AS [PartyCode]
        FROM     [PanERP].[Pricing] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [PanERP].[PricingDetail] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PricingId] = [Extent2].[PricingId]
        INNER JOIN [PanERP].[PricingTagDetail] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[PricingDetailId] = [Extent3].[PricingDetailId]
        INNER JOIN [PanERP].[Item] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[ItemId] = [Extent4].[ItemId]
        INNER JOIN [PanERP].[Party] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent3].[PartyId] = [Extent5].[PartyId]
        WHERE [Extent3].[AvailableQuantity] > cast(0 as decimal(18))

) AS [Filter1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [PanERP].[Brand] AS [Extent6] ON [Filter1].[BrandId1] = [Extent6].[BrandId]
    WHERE ([Filter1].[PricingNo] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Filter1].[PricingNo] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
```

But When i change the condition

> where tagDtl.AvailableQuantity > 0m

as a variable it creates another SQL query without nested select statement.

Here is the modified code

```
decimal availableQuantity = 0m;
var pricingInfo = (from price in invDB.Pricing.AsNoTracking()
                                join priceD in invDB.PricingDetail.AsNoTracking() on price.PricingId equals priceDtl.PricingId
                               join tagD in invDB.PricingTagDetail.AsNoTracking() on priceDtl.PricingDetailId equals tagDtl.PricingDetailId
                               join it in invDB.Item.AsNoTracking() on tagDtl.ItemId equals item.ItemId
                               join par in invDB.Party.AsNoTracking() on tagDtl.PartyId equals party.PartyId
                               join b in invDB.Brand.AsNoTracking() on tagDtl.BrandId equals brd.BrandId into t from brand in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               where tagDtl.AvailableQuantity > availableQuantity && price.PricingNo == printNumber
                               select new
                               {
                                   TagNo = tagDtl.TagNo,
                                   SellingRate = tagDtl.SellingRate,
                                   Quantity = tagDtl.AvailableQuantity ?? availableQuantity,
                                   ItemCode = item.Name,
                                   UOMId = priceDtl.UOMId,
                                   Brand = brand.BrandCode,
                                   Supplier = party.PartyCode,
                                   Offer = tagDtl.Offer
                               }).ToList();
```

and here is the SQL query without nested SQL statement.

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[PricingId] AS [PricingId],
    [Extent3].[TagNo] AS [TagNo],
    [Extent3].[SellingRate] AS [SellingRate],
    CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[AvailableQuantity] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as decimal(18)) ELSE [Extent3].[AvailableQuantity] END AS [C1],
    [Extent4].[Name] AS [Name],
    [Extent2].[UOMId ] AS [UOMId ],
    [Extent6].[BrandCode] AS [BrandCode],
    [Extent5].[PartyCode] AS [PartyCode],
    [Extent3].[Offer] AS [Offer]
    FROM      [PanERP].[Pricing] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [PanERP].[PricingDetail] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PricingId] = [Extent2].[PricingId]
    INNER JOIN [PanERP].[PricingTagDetail] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[PricingDetailId] = [Extent3].[PricingDetailId]
    INNER JOIN [PanERP].[Item] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[ItemId] = [Extent4].[ItemId]
    INNER JOIN [PanERP].[Party] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent3].[PartyId] = [Extent5].[PartyId]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [PanERP].[Brand] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent3].[BrandId] = [Extent6].[BrandId]
    WHERE ([Extent3].[AvailableQuantity] > @p__linq__0) AND (([Extent1].[PricingNo] = @p__linq__1) OR (([Extent1].[PricingNo] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL)))
```

If I move the where condition to the model definition as lambda expression, like this

> from price in inventoryDb.Pricing.AsNoTracking().Where(c =>
>   c.PricingNo == printNumber))

then also it works fine.

Why is LINQ generating a nested Select? How can we avoid this?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: The SQL contains a sub query, without where condition. Where condition is outside the sub query and it pulls out full records from a large volume data(20 Crores). This results to a heavy memory consumption and performance issues on my DB server.

Comment: both are same, I have updated the query. AvailableQuantity is decimal?

Comment: The first query took 40 seconds to run and the second query took only 1 second.

Comment: price.PricingNo is string. If I move price.PricingNo == printNumber to join, then also it works fine.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend moving both of your conditions from the WHERE to the JOIN clauses.

Comment: AvailableQuantity is decimal (in the database)

Comment: I'd be good to get some actual plan insight  (maybe from dba-stackexchange) why the subquery changes the performance, I'd bet it's the left outer join / priceNo filtering performed on a smaller dataset

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you have answered your own question, on your comments. I will just try to clarify what is going on.

When you use a hard-coded constant, like 0m, the framework translates it into SQL keeping the value as a constant:

`WHERE [Extent3].[AvailableQuantity] > cast(0 as decimal(18))`

When you use a local variable, like “availableQuantity”, the framework creates a parameter:

`([Extent3].[AvailableQuantity] > @p__linq__0)`

I might be wrong, but, as I see, this is done in order to preserve the programmer’s goal when writing the code (constant = constant, variable = parameter).

**And what about the subquery?**

This is a query optimization logic (a bad one, probably, at least on this scenario). When you make a query using parameters, you might run it several times, but SQL Server will always use the same execution plan, making the query faster; when you use constants, each query need to be reevaluated (if you check SQL Server Activity Monitor, you will see that queries with parameters are treated as the same query, regardless the parameters values).

This way, in my opinion (sorry, I could not find any documentation about it), **Entity Framework is trying to isolate the queries; the outer/generic one, that use parameters, and the inner/specific one, that use constants.**

I would be happy if anyone could complement it with some Microsoft documentation about this subject…

Comment: Oooooooh that is very interesting and might explain the behaviour.